# How long will canned cooked clams last in fridge after opened?

Tags: shellfish

How long will canned cooked clams last after can has been opened- and been refrigerated? OK to eat after 7 days? (No weird smell detected)

Comment: Refer to the "Shelf stable until opened" section in the answer above.